# Form based authentication FBA - keeps getting "Make sure your user name and password are correct"

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, central-administration

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 Foundation.

I have followed a few tutorials on getting the Form Based Authentication to work:

http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/configuring-forms-based-authentication.html
http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider.aspx
http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-2-adding-users-to-the-membership-database/
http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2011/06/19/configure-form-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

I have done the following:
Setup membership SQL DB
configure 3 web.config files
Setup settings in SP central admin
Installed the FBA pack from:  http://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/

I can add users into my membership DB through Site Setting -> "FBA User Management" OR "People and Group" and I can search the user I have created in membership DB

But Everytime I try to log in, I get: The server could not sign you in. Make sure your user name and password are correct, and then try again.

When I looked at event log, it says: "An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The security token username and password could not be validated.."
In the details tab, it says: "The security token username and password could not be validated."

Noticed there's a extra 'full stop' in the error msg, does it tell anything?

How can I debug this? or get more detailed error message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you can add users to the FBA Pack, but you can't login, that means that your SharePoint web application web.config/machine.config membership settings are good, but your SecurityTokenService web.config settings are not. Check your SecurityTokenService web.config membership settings and compare them to your web application web.config/machine.config membership settings.

Details are in the second half of this page:
http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-3-editing-the-web-config-files/

Answer (score 1):

I had implemented FBA and done this two part blog on my site. Please have a look at the steps I have followed and verify that you are't missing anything. Below given are the links to my blogs that explains FBA implementation. First blog describes how to create Membership Provider and role provider and prepare the DB. Second blog describes how to make SharePoint aware of the membership providers you have created by modifying the web.config files at various levels.

Part 1:

http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/Form-Based-Authentication-FBA-in-SharePoint-2010-part-1.aspx

Part 2:
http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/Form-Based-Authentication-FBA-in-SharePoint-2010-part-2.aspx

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Nice to know it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

My configuration was setup correctly, however it seems this error may just be a simple authentication error. Make sure:

- The account you're attempting to login with is actually in or below the `userContainer` (you can also use ldp.exe to confirm container names etc).
- Ensure the `User Policy` on your `Web Application` actually let's you login with an Admin User first and then you can configure permissions... we have just setup "Everyone" as a Visitor user at this stage:

[image]