# Different Authentication methods in a Single SharePoint farm

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have to build up a system based on Dynamics CRM online and SharePoint 2013 on Premise in a Windows Azure Machine. Employees from the company access Dynamics to register the customers, products, offers and so on. The customers of the company log in the SharePoint portal to view their offers, products, etc. using webservices that connects to Dynamics Online.

The company requirement is that their employees must sign in either Dynamics online or SharePoint portal with their AD credentials, and external users should use another way of authentication (FBA, claims or whatever) introducing username and password. How could I set up both ways of authentication? Each customer of the company would consume a CAL license? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a mix of two different solution.

The first is create a new entity with a connection to a Contact entity where store username and password.
Create a new ASP .NET membership provider database.
Create custom workflow that populate it.

The second is configure a standard SQL [membership provider](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/) in your SharePoint 2013 Online that retrieve data from a SQL Server DB.

I suggest you this solution because you use SharePoint Online. Otherwise a [custom membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) was the best way.

Bye.

Comment: I am not sure taht you can the the second method in a SharePoint Online but in on Premise. Where do yo configure MemberShip provider in SharePoint online? In the first option a Workflow is not necessary, you could do it with an authentication page. the other question is if you consume a CAL license

Answer (score 1):

I agree to the above answer. If you would want to find more details as to a step by step example, see the links provided in this answer.

[Check my answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/79023/19195)

Comment: Ok. this solutions fits up to 90%  of my requirement but is there any way to bypass the login page and check that if you have SPContext with Active directory account enter directly to the page and if you are an external user be prompted with the user and password credentials?

Comment: you could think of using custom login page where you can do customize your UI.

Comment: the problem is that the users and passwords are in CRM and if I activate FBA I don't know how to say to the membership provider that accesses to the CRM database (via Web services, CRM object model or whatever) Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. Will come back if I get something.

Comment: I have seen that you can code a custom Membership and role provider to connecto to Dynamics CRM http://crmmembership.codeplex.com/

Comment: So go ahead and let me know when your are successful.

Comment: It worked. The only issue is that you have a page where you have to choose the auth method

Comment: Nice to know that it worked.