# Security token username and password cannot be validated

Tags: 2010, claims-based-auth, security-token-service

we are having trouble in generating security token for anonymous login.
We have two kinds of login:

1. Usual username and password (Registered)
2. Using the 2 user's info(Unregistered/Anonymous)

We are using Claims Based Authentication, Sharepoint 2010.

Anonymous login was working perfectly around 2 weeks before, but now it does not.

User is redirected to login page instead of the destined page.

Web configs for STS, Services, Virtual Directories are the same.
ULS logs:

> - w3wp.exe (0x4200)  0x09F0  SharePoint Foundation   Claims    Authentication    Critical    An exception occurred when trying to issue
>     security token: The security token username and password could not be 
>     validated..
> - w3wp.exe    (0x4200)   0x09F0  SharePoint Foundation   Claims Authentication   Could not    rebuild forms user token.
> - w3wp.exe (0x5450)  0x09E0  SharePoint    Foundation    Claims Authentication   User '{0}' not found.
> - w3wp.exe   (0x5450)    0x09E0  SharePoint Foundation   Claims Authentication   Failed   validation on user ''.
> - w3wp.exe    (0x5450)   0x09E0  SharePoint Foundation   Claims    Authentication    SPSecurityTokenService.Issue() failed:
>     System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.FailedAuthenticationException]:
>     The security token username and password could not be validated.
>     (Fault Detail is equal to
>     Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.FailedAuthenticationException: The
>     security token username and password could not be validated.).
> - w3wp.exe (0x4200)  0x1E44  SharePoint Foundation   Claims    Authentication    Request for security token failed with exception:
>     System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The security token username and
>     password could not be validated.     at
>     Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.ReadResponse(Message
>     response)     at
>     Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken
>     rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)     at
>     Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken
>     rst)     at
>     Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri
>     context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken 
>     actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo)
> - w3wp.exe (0x4200) 0x1E44  SharePoint Foundation   Claims    Authentication    An exception occurred when trying to issue security
>     token: The security token username and password could not be
>     validated..

What else could be cause of the issue?

**Update**

Custom login, which the anonymous or unregistered user uses, uses SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormUser(uri, username, password).

Comment: Have you recite the sts app pool?

Comment: hi @WaqasSarwarMCSE, what do you mean by reciting the sts app pool?

Comment: I am sorry it was typo as send from mobile....I mean recycle the sts app pool

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE, based from the setting, sts app pool is not recycled.

Comment: I mean try to recycle it and see if that fix

Comment: Also go to IIS Manager –> Sites –> SharePoint WebServices –> SecurityTokenServiceApplication, click on ‘Content View’ down at the bottom, right click on Securitytoken.svc and click Browse...what u are seeing here

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE, this is what I'm seeing, Error: Security policy export failed. The binding contains a TransportSecurityBindingElement but no transport binding element that implements ITransportTokenAssertionProvider. But, we fixed this in other dev server, and it did not made any difference.

Comment: after fixing that, are you seeing the text with green color?

Comment: yup, i am. is it the comments that you are referring to?  // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.  

        // Always close the client.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that you have followed the correct steps provided from Microsoft article at [Configure forms-based authentication for a claims-based Web application (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806890(v=office.14).aspx) and [Configure Forms Based Authentication (FBA) with SharePoint 2010](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mahesm/2010/04/07/configure-forms-based-authentication-fba-with-sharepoint-2010/)
- Make sure that [the Service account that run Central administrtion has been added to your FBA database.](http://suryapulipati.blogspot.com/2012/06/exception-occurred-when-trying-to-issue.html)
- Navigate to Navigate to `“C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config” and open “machine.config”.` Make sure the server name is the same across all applications that use the FBA.
- Naivigate to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebServices\SecurityToken\web.config` and make sure that “ApplicationName” property set to (recommend “/”)

To do that check [Configuring Forms-Based Authentication in SharePoint 2013 – Part 3 – Editing the Web.Config Files](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-3-editing-the-web-config-files/)

Also check another reasons at [Form based authentication FBA - keeps getting "Make sure your user name and password are correct"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79011/form-based-authentication-fba-keeps-getting-make-sure-your-user-name-and-pass)

Comment: Thanks for this, @M.Qassas. I have compared the said file and they are the same. I have also used the web.config from pre prod and in my dev environment (both are working) but for this specific environment it did not. Also, upon checking the ULS logs, it seems that it failed to get the account set in Application Pool for user impersonation.